# How to code Queue in Java

Tags: java, queue

I'm trying to make a Queue in java.

The problem is that I don't know how to remove(?) a value from the array, the index value which I dequeue.

This is my code.
front() method is the dequeue part. and I used iter_ to set the current index position.
but as you can see, it dequeue's the corret value though the value still remains inside the array:(

```
public class IntQueue {

    private int[] items_;
    private int top_;
    private int capacity_;
    private int iter_;

    public IntQueue(int capacity)
    {
        if(capacity <=0) capacity = 10;

        capacity_ = capacity;
        top_=0;
        count_ = 0;
        iter_=0;

        items_= new int[capacity_];
    }

    public void push_back(int value)
    {
        if(top_>= capacity_)
            overflow();

        items_[top_++]=value;
        count_++;
    }

    public int front()
    {
        if(top_<=0)
            return 0;

        int temp=0;
        temp=items_[iter_];

        count_--;
        iter_++;
        return temp;

    }

    public IntQueue clone()
    {
        IntQueue result = new IntQueue(capacity_);

        for(int i=0 ; i<top_; ++i)
        {
            result.push_back(items_[i]);

        }

        /*for(int i=0 ; i<top_ ; ++i)
        {

            result.items_[i] = items_[i];
        }*/

        return result;

    }

    public void log()
    {

        for(int i=0 ; i <top_; ++i)
        {
            System.out.print(items_[i]);
            if(i<top_ -1)
                System.out.print(", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        }

    }

    private void overflow()
    {
        int[] newItem = new int[capacity_*2];

        for(int i=0 ; i <top_; ++i)
            newItem[i] = items_[i];
        items_=newItem;
        capacity_ *=2;

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        IntQueue queue = new IntQueue(2);

        System.out.println("queue push 3: "); queue.push_back(3);
        System.out.println("queue push 2: "); queue.push_back(2);
        System.out.println("queue push 1: "); queue.push_back(1);

        System.out.print("queue log: "); queue.log();

        System.out.println("front " + queue.front());
        System.out.println("front " + queue.front());

        System.out.print("queue log: "); queue.log();

        System.out.println("queue push 12: "); queue.push_back(12);
        System.out.println("queue push 11: "); queue.push_back(11);
        System.out.println("queue push 21: "); queue.push_back(21);
        System.out.println("queue push 31: "); queue.push_back(31);

        System.out.print("queue log: "); queue.log();

        System.out.println("front " + queue.front());
        System.out.println("front " + queue.front());

        System.out.print("clone queue log: "); queue.clone().log();


    }

}
```

Comment: Have you seen the Java's [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) yet?

Comment: @sblck.. Common man, you don't have to ReInvent the Wheel. Java already has it as the link given by asgs

Comment: @RohitJain Actually: It is a very good exrecise. "Reinventing the wheel" for educational purposes is perfectly valid and should definetly be encouraged.

Comment: @amit. Well you are right.. I second that.. And apologies for my previous comment..

Answer (score 4):

What I don't get about your implementation is the following:

- in the front method you're using `iter_`, but nowhere else. What is it good for?
- if you're not using some kind of variable to keep track of what was removed without actually removing it, technically you'd need to shift all the items of the array to the left by one position, such that the first item is gone. This however is an O(N) operation.
- It's easier to implement a queue using a linked list instead of an array.

Answer (score 3):

When building a queue using an array, you can make a **cyclic "pointer"** to the head of the array, that you can use to retrieve the top.

Popping from the array is simply done by increasing this cyclic pointer.

Maintain an `int` variable: `top`, and once you need to pop an element do `top = (top + 1) % items_.length`

Retrieving the head is simple using `items_[top]`.

Make sure you are guarding against popping elements that are not there (popping from an empty array).

You will probably also need to maintan a `size` variable for the queue's size.

Comment: +1 This is what I would do as remove is O(1). I would call this a ring buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Below I share my proposed solution for a simple thread-safe FIFO queue :D

```
public class Queue extends Object {

    private int numElements;

    private Node first;
    private Node last;

    /**
     * Helper linked list class 
     */
    private static class Node {
        private Object item;
        private Node next;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Queue object. 
     */
    public Queue() {
        numElements = 0;
        first = last = null;
    }

    /**
     * Puts an object at the end of the queue.
     * 
     * @param object 
     */
    public void putObject(Object object) {

        synchronized (this) {

            Node newNode = new Node();
            newNode.item = object;
            newNode.next = null;

            if ( numElements == 0 ) {
                first = last = newNode;
            } else {
                last.next = newNode;
                last = newNode;
            }

            numElements += 1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets an object from the beginning of the queue. The object is removed
     * from the queue. If there are no objects in the queue, returns null.
     */
    public Object getObject() {

        synchronized (this) {

            Object item = null;

            if ( numElements > 0 ) {

                item = first.item;
                first = first.next;

                numElements -= 1;

                if (numElements == 0) {
                    last = null;
                }
            } 

            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this: it has `enqueue` and `dequeue` methods:

```
 import java.io.*;  
 import java.lang.*;  
 class clrqueue  
 {  
  DataInputStream get=new DataInputStream(System.in);  
  int a[];  
  int i,front=0,rear=0,n,item,count=0;  
  void getdata()  
  {  
  try  
   {  
   System.out.println("Enter the limit");  
   n=Integer.parseInt(get.readLine());  
   a=new int[n];  
   }   
  catch(Exception e)  
   {  
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
   }  
  }  
  void enqueue()  
  {  
   try  
   {  
   if(count<n)  
    {  
    System.out.println("Enter the element to be added:");  
    item=Integer.parseInt(get.readLine());  
    a[rear]=item;  
     rear++;  
    count++;  
    }  
   else  
    System.out.println("QUEUE IS FULL");  
   }  
  catch(Exception e)  
   {  
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
   }  
  }  
  void dequeue()  
  {  
   if(count!=0)  
    {  
    System.out.println("The item deleted is:"+a[front]);  
    front++;  
    count--;  
    }  
   else  
    System.out.println("QUEUE IS EMPTY");  
  if(rear==n)  
   rear=0;  
  }  
  void display()  
  {  
   int m=0;  
   if(count==0)  
   System.out.println("QUEUE IS EMPTY");  
   else  
   {  
   for(i=front;m<count;i++,m++)  
   System.out.println(" "+a[i]);  
   }  
  }  
 }  
 class Myqueue  
 {  
  public static void main(String arg[])  
  {  
  DataInputStream get=new DataInputStream(System.in);  
  int ch;  
  clrqueue obj=new clrqueue();  
  obj.getdata();  
  try  
  {  
   do  
   {  
   System.out.println(" 1.Enqueue  2.Dequeue  3.Display  4.Exit");  
   System.out.println("Enter the choice");  
   ch=Integer.parseInt(get.readLine());  
   switch (ch)  
   {  
   case 1:  
       obj.enqueue();  
      break;  
   case 2:  
      obj.dequeue();  
      break;  
   case 3:  
      obj.display();  
      break;  
   }  
   }  
   while(ch!=4);  
  }  
  catch(Exception e)  
  {  
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
  }  
  }  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

when you design a queue, you need to decide the priority like how you are going to add and remove element from it.You can go through this link and implement it similar to this.
[FIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO)

A typical example is :

```
 import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class QueueExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Queue<String> qe=new LinkedList<String>();

        qe.add("b");
        qe.add("a");
        qe.add("c");
        qe.add("e");
        qe.add("d");

        Iterator it=qe.iterator();

        System.out.println("Initial Size of Queue :"+qe.size());

        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            String iteratorValue=(String)it.next();
            System.out.println("Queue Next Value :"+iteratorValue);
        }

        // get value and does not remove element from queue
        System.out.println("Queue peek :"+qe.peek());

        // get first value and remove that object from queue
        System.out.println("Queue poll :"+qe.poll());

        System.out.println("Final Size of Queue :"+qe.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant remove an element from an array like a List. You need to move the values up and set the last index of the array as null. Take a look at the source of a java class that implement `Queue.remove()` method. For example following is the code from `removeAt(int index)` method of `ArrayBlockingQueue`.

```
void removeAt(int i) {
        final E[] items = this.items;
        // if removing front item, just advance
        if (i == takeIndex) {
            items[takeIndex] = null;
            takeIndex = inc(takeIndex);
        } else {
            // slide over all others up through putIndex.
            for (;;) {
                int nexti = inc(i);
                if (nexti != putIndex) {
                    items[i] = items[nexti];
                    i = nexti;
                } else {
                    items[i] = null;
                    putIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        --count;
        notFull.signal();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't delete an item from an array, you can just overwrite it. You can use a `List` instead.

Another option is to use a circular queue, as amit's answer pointed out.

A simple solution using array is:

```
int queue[SIZE];
int first = 0;
int last = 0;

void enque(int i) {
    if(last == SIZE)
        throw new RuntimeExeption("Queue is full");
    queue[last++] = i;
}

int deque() {
    if(first == last)
        throw new RuntimeExeption("Queue is empty");
    return queue[first++];
}
```

Comment: Actually `ArrayList` is a bad choice for a queue. a `LinkedList` is much more efficient for this purpose. But using the `List` interface is of course a good approach to build a queue.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code i implemented and is working fine in my system.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Queue {

public int[] queue = new int[3];

int head = -1, tail =-1;

public void enqueue(int N){
    if(tail == (queue.length-1))
        queue = Arrays.copyOf(queue,2*queue.length);
    if(head == -1){
        head++;
        tail++;
        queue[head] = N;
    }
    else {
        tail++;
        queue[tail] = N;
    }

}

public int dequeue(){
    if(head == -1)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot dequeue if queue is empty");
    int firstItem = queue[head];
    if (head == tail) {
        head = -1;
        tail = -1;
    }
    else
        head++;
    return firstItem;
}

public void display(){
    for (int i = head; i<= tail ; i++){
        System.out.println("Display: " + queue[i]);
    }
 }
}
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Queue queue = new Queue();
    queue.enqueue(10);
    queue.enqueue(20);
    queue.enqueue(30);
    queue.enqueue(40);
    queue.display();
    int dequeue = queue.dequeue();
    System.out.println(dequeue);
    queue.display();
    int dequeue1 = queue.dequeue();
    System.out.println(dequeue1);
    queue.display();
 }
}
```